# How Does Erdas calculates the ground coordinates for each pixel in the image

Tags: erdas-imagine, photogrammetry

How Does Erdas calculates the ground coordinates for each pixel in the image

I have a conceptual question regarding photogrammetry, what is the formula used by Erdas to find the (X,Y,Z) on ground. Erdas requires inputs like ( focal length, H of the plane, image exteriors (x,y,z, omega, phi, kappa), GCPs, pixel size) then the result is an orthophoto that have accurate coordinates, but I am curious on how does this software calculates the ground coordinate for each pixel in the image ! 
Is there any formulas/references on this, can I calculate a coordinate for one pixel manually just to check that the software is working fine or just to prove it for myself.

Comment: Do you particularly want to know how Erdas does it, or do you want the general formulas?

Comment: It would be great if I lean how exactly Erdas does it